ESP32 async scan networks returning fail even though successful scan. How do I detect a real fail
Environment ESP32-WROOM-32UE.
I need to run WiFi.scanNetworks() asynchronously for my project. My sample code returns a list of discovered networks however the output during WiFi.scanComplete() does not make sense. Snippet from test code:
void _scan_check() {
   int asyncscan = WiFi.scanNetworks(true);
   delay(1000);
   int status = WiFi.scanComplete();
   while(status < 0) {
    Serial.printf("Status = %d", status);
    delay(1000);
    status = WiFi.scanComplete();
   }
   Serial.printf("Status = %d", status);
}

When run I get the following output (commented):
Status = -1  //equal to WIFI_SCAN_RUNNING
Status = -1  //equal to WIFI_SCAN_RUNNING
Status = -1  //equal to WIFI_SCAN_RUNNING
Status = -1  //equal to WIFI_SCAN_RUNNING
Status = -2  //equal to WIFI_SCAN_FAILED
Status = -2  //equal to WIFI_SCAN_FAILED
Status = 7   // discovered 7 networks

This happens regardless of how many networks discovered. So my question is, why do I always get one or more WIFI_SCAN_FAILED prior to getting the actual count of discovered networks and how do I detect a real scan fail?
Is this an undocumented way it works or is there some bug with the ESP32 backend code?

This has something to do with your network or your network environment, nothing wrong with your code and certainly not an ESP32 bug. If you switch to another network, you might not get the WIFI_SCAN_FAILED.

(This is apparently dependent on the Arduino SDK version used. I'm using v2.0.16 locally. )
I've just faced the same problem and it seems to be a race condition between timeout detection in scanComplete() and the underlying event system which reports completion to the Arduino WiFi library. (Ref - Handling of ESP32 events and internal callback for its own tracking.)
I viewed the underlying event logs by adding this to my build flags: -DCORE_DEBUG_LEVEL=5, and some println debugging shows that the timeout condition returns a failure before the ARDUINO_EVENT_WIFI_SCAN_DONE is received, which would've normally been caught by the rest of that function.
It appears to have been fixed with this PR for v3.0.0. Locally I can confirm that the issue is fixed when I manually apply the change.

... and how do I detect a real scan fail?

The update from that PR fixes the timeout issue, but I don't see anything checking the wifi_scan_done field of that event which would tell you whether the scan was a success or failure.
As a workaround, you could use WiFi.onEvent manually to detect completion + failures.
